How to Use WebSockets to Check if a Token Mint Address is Tradable on Raydium?
Does anyone here know how to check if the given token mint address is already tradable using WebSocket? My current code polls the token holders and checks if Raydium already exists as a holder. But it is very slow for sniping, I don't think that is the best way to do it.
I know how to check for newly added liquidity pools by subscribing to the RAYDIUM_V4_ADDRESS using WebSocket. However, I am not looking to subscribe to newly added liquidity pools for all tokens. I want to subscribe to a specific token mint address, but I don't know how to determine if the logs are for Raydium trading allowance.
Could someone advise me on how to do that using WebSocket? Thanks!
My current code that uses polling:
@async_timed
async def check_raydium_authority_for_token_retry(
        mint_address: Pubkey,
        duration_hours: float = CHECK_RAYDIUM_AUTHORITY_DURATION_HOURS
) -> bool or None:
    """
    Check for the presence of the Raydium Authority V4 address for a token mint
    and keep checking for up to 'duration_hours'.
    """
    opts = TokenAccountOpts(mint=mint_address)
    end_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=duration_hours)

    while datetime.datetime.now() < end_time:
        response = await solana_async_client.get_token_accounts_by_owner_json_parsed(
            owner=RAYDIUM_AUTHORITY_V4_ADDRESS,
            opts=opts,
            commitment=Finalized,
        )

        # Safely access 'value' attribute, defaulting to None if it's not present
        response_value = getattr(response, 'value', None)

        if response_value:
            for account_info in response_value:
                account_data = account_info.account.data
                if isinstance(account_data, ParsedAccount):
                    parsed_info = account_data.parsed
                    if "info" in parsed_info and parsed_info["info"]["mint"] == str(mint_address):
                        LOGGER.success(f"Raydium Authority V4 address found for token")
                        return True

        await asyncio.sleep(CHECK_RAYDIUM_AUTHORITY_DELAY_SECONDS)

    LOGGER.error(f"Raydium Authority V4 address not found for token within {duration_hours} hour(s).")
    return None


Would this help?
https://www.helius.dev/blog/how-to-fetch-newly-minted-tokens-with-helius
Explains how to set up a websocket to check the tokens. You'd still have to filter out the Raydium tokens (perhaps by checking the liquidity pool)

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
